# C# Generic method for list of different objects

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I have a situation in C# web api function where I will need to retrieve a list of different objects from my database and need to implement some logic by invoking various methods.

How can I better achieve this by writing a Generic function for all 3 objects

example

there are two scenarios of locking list

1. whole list is locked (do not proceed and throw exception if whole
   list is locked)
2. only a single entity is locked (filter and remove
   this element if locked from the list)

   ```
   List<Object1> list1;
   List<Object2> list2;
   List<Object3> list3;

   private FilterLockedEntities(List<Object1> list1){

      if(list1[0].isListLocked) //whole list is locked
        throw ValidationException("Message")

      list1.RemoveAll(a => a.IsLocked); //filter locked entities

      //some more logic common to all

   }

   private FilterLockedEntities(List<Object2> list2){

      if(list2[0].isListLocked) //whole list is locked
        throw ValidationException("Message")

      list2.RemoveAll(a => a.IsLocked); //filter locked entities

      //some more logic common to all

   }

   private FilterLockedEntities(List<Object3> list3){

      if(list3[0].isListLocked) //whole list is locked
        throw ValidationException("Message")

      list3.RemoveAll(a => a.IsLocked); //filter locked entities

      //some more logic common to all

   }
   ```

I have the same logic in each of the three function but with List of different entities.

Is there a way where I can use a single method instead of three different functions its hard to maintain due to redundant logic. If there is a change in logic it needs to be updated in all the three places.

Comment: Can you change the definition of the objects? One easy way would be to just implement an interface with the "IsLocked" field.

Comment: Does the code in `//some more logic common to all` do anything with the lists? If so, what & how? If not, why is the code there?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new interface:

```
public interface ILockable
{
    bool isListLocked();
}
```

Then make your object inherit the interface in their class declarations:

```
class Object1 : ILockable
{
    public IsLocked()
    {
        // Your code here...
    }
}
...
class Object2 : ILockable ...
class Object3 : ILockable ...
```

Then make your function accept a `List` of `ILockable` objects:

```
private FilterLockedEntities(List<ILockable> list)
{
    // Your code here...
}
```

Comment: Since `List<Object1>` is *not* `List<ILockable>` this suggestion would be pain to implement as-is.

Comment: I was assuming `Object1` thru `Object3` were custom types and that the OP could modify the types by simply adding the interface inheritance, since the methods are already implemented on the object.  If this is not the case, then yes, it would necessitate creating derived objects to implement.

Comment: You really should try to pass `List<Object1>` to your method and see what happens. Creating copy of `List<Object1>` just to call your method is not very good solution.

Comment: `List` objects are passed by reference in C#.  My answer as proposed involves no copying of anything.

Comment: Casting List<Object1> to List<ILockable> creates a new list and the changes like remove from list to List<ILockable> doesn't reflect in the List<Object1>

Comment: There is no casting involved in the solution I proposed.  Object1 inherits from ILockable and therefore for an Object1 instance `object1`, `(object1 is ILockable)` would evaluate as true.  No casting, no converting, no copying.

Comment: @Dave, yes `(object1 is ILockable)` is `true` when `object1` is of type `Object1`, but `(listOfObject1 is List<ILockable>)` is `false` when `listOfObject1` is of type `List<Object1>` because `List<T>` is not covariant (like `IEnumerable<out T>`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `dynamic`

```
private FilterLockedEntities(dynamic list1){

   if(list1[0].isListLocked) //whole list is locked
     throw ValidationException("Message")

   list1.RemoveAll(a => a.IsLocked); //filter locked entities

   //some more logic common to all

}
```

A little unnecessarily broad for my tastes but perhaps fits your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add an interface `IObject` to `Object1`, `Object2`, and `Object3`, then more generics are the answer:

```
public interface IObject
{
    bool isLockedList { get; }
    bool IsLocked { get; }
}

private void FilterLockedEntities<T>(List<T> list) where T : IObject
{
    // same code as above should work here...
}
```